# Error while installing openldap server on ubuntu 14.04 mkdir: cannot create directory `/etc/ldap/slapd.conf': File exists

Tags: restore, configure, ubuntu-14.04, openldap

I am trying to setup ldap server on my ubuntu 14.04. I had previous ldap server setup installed on centos 6 which uses flat-file configuration i.e slapd.conf method for ldap.

Now I want to setup openldap server on Ubuntu 14.04.
 I placed all contents from /etc/openldap from centos in /etc/ldap on ubuntu.
When  I try to install ldap using following

```
$ sudo apt-get install slapd
```

I am getting below error:

```
Setting up slapd (2.4.31-1ubuntu2) ...
  Creating initial configuration... mkdir: cannot create directory `/etc/ldap/slapd.conf': File exists
dpkg: error processing slapd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 slapd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I removed database files from /var/lib/ldap/

```
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/ldap/*
```

Then, I tried it to convert slapd.conf to slapd.d by using

```
$ sudo slaptest -f slapd.conf -F slapd.d
```

I am get error as below.

```
Unrecognized database type (bdb)  
546470b0 slapd.conf: line 99: <database> failed init (bdb)  
slaptest: bad configuration directory!
```

What should be done in order to use slapd.conf of my own and configure database.

Answer (score 0):

The following command converts a slapd.conf to slapd.d:

```
slaptest -f slapd.conf -F slapd.d
```

Comment: I removed slapd.conf from /etc/ldap and then reinstalled slapd. It installed initial configuration which uses hdb. I then copied my slapd.conf into /etc/ldap directory.  After running slaptest I am getting this error.    `Unrecognized database type (bdb) 5450c005 slapd.conf: line 99: <database> failed init (bdb) slaptest: bad configuration directory!`

Comment: So you need to install it such that BDB is included in the configuration.

Comment: I removed the bdb created while initial configuration by removing contents. `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/ldap/*` Then I have tried to install database from ldif file.  Used follwing for same  `sudo slapadd -l mypreviousdb.ldif`  It throws error as  `54535b8b ldif_read_file: checksum error on "/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif"
54535b8d olcDbDirectory: value #0: invalid path: No such file or directory
54535b8d config error processing olcDatabase={1}bdb,cn=config: olcDbDirectory: value #0: invalid path: No such file or directory
slapadd: bad configuration file!
`